# What is the exact set-up for a websocket server on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket

I am running a little node.js server on Heroku for a websocket application.  After doing a lot of research, I still can't figure out how to optimise my set-up on Heroku, and I am seeing a lot of H15 (time-out) errors on Heroku.

So what is the complete list of services and packages that I have to install for the best set-up, i.e., Nginx, Trace, etc..?

I am currently using 
 - node.js, 
 - with express, 
 - socketio, and 
 - throng 
installed.  At one point I also installed an Nginx server, but this did not seem to make a difference, performance wise.

Any further suggestions?